# Illustrator: how to select multiple shapes to apply the same style

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

Is it possible to select multiple shapes at a time in Illustrator? I have a number of shapes in my artwork that have some common styles, and I would like to select all of them at same time. I've tried using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key with no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to select more than one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Select objects by clicking with the black arrow tool. To select multiple objects hold down the shift key while clicking additional objects, or take the black arrow tool and draw a square around the objects you want to edit. Once you have them all selected you can edit them all at once. Unless you can't. If they already have different fills and strokes it may not let you apply new to all at once. With them all selected hit the default fill and stroke (black and white on the tools palet) this should reset them and allow you to apply new effects.